# Conway's Game of Life Next Generation Function (Python)

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I have just one (most likely) last question. From when I sent my last question, I have progressed a bit and I have coded 5/6 functions so far (1, 2, 3, 5, and 6), and function 4 is really just putting together functions 5 and 6, which is what I need help with. These are the functions I am using to create Conway's Game of Life:

Function 1: create a blank grid
input: nothing
return: a blank grid

Function 2: print a given grid
input: a grid
return: nothing

Function 3: load a pattern
input: a file name, a grid
return: nothing

Function 4: advance a grid one generation
input: a grid
return: a new grid advanced by one generation

Function 5: advance a cell one generation
input: a row, a column, a grid
return: whether the cell is alive or not (True or False)

Function 6: determine the number of living neighbors of a cell
input: a row, a column, a grid
return: the number of living neighbors of the cell

This is my code so far:

```
living_cell = "O"
dead_cell = "-"

# There was more code here before. I removed it for the sake of brevity

def num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid):
    living_neighbors_count = 0
    if grid[row][col + 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    if grid[row][col - 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    if grid[row + 1][col] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    if grid[row - 1][col] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    if grid[row + 1][col + 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    if grid[row + 1][col - 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    if grid[row - 1][col + 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    if grid[row - 1][col - 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    return living_neighbors_count


def adv_cell_one_gen(row, col, grid):

    # is alive, less than 2 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) < 2:
        return False

    # is alive, 2 or 3 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and (
            num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 2 or num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 3):
        return True

    # is alive, more than 4 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) > 4:
        return False
    # is dead, has 3 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == dead_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 3:
        return True


def adv_grid_one_gen(grid):


    for i in grid:
        for j in i:
            if adv_cell_one_gen(j, i, grid) == True:
                grid[i][j] = living_cell
            else:
                grid[i][j] = dead_cell
    return grid

adv_grid_one_gen(create_blank_grid)
```

Function 1: create_blank_grid

Function 2: print_grid

Function 3: load_design

Function 4: adv_grid_one_gen

Function 5: adv_cell_one_gen

Function 6: num_living_neighbors

I am having difficulty in function 4, advancing the whole grid by one generation, by using function 5 and iterating through the whole grid.

My question here is that when I try to run this, I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvjkU.png)

This was my question and I hope you can help. Again, I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you cannot answer this, please say why in a comment so I can know how to improve my questions from now on.

Comment: @Prune  I tried to shorten it as much as I could while keeping it readable and understandable. Is it good enough now?

Answer (score 2):

In `adv_grid_one_gen`, maybe you want to change

```py
    for i in grid:
        for j in i:
```

to

```py
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
```

You want `i` and `j` to be integers, not strings/lists of strings, right?

Comment: Well, I tried it and I got an IndexError on the line that is "if grid[row + 1][col] == living_cell"

Comment: That makes sense. You tried to access a "neighbor" that is outside of the grid. How to fix that is up to you: you could add a check for that or you could have it "wrap" around or whatever behavior you want to do.

Comment: I would like it to wrap around, but how would I implement that in function 5 (num_living_neighbors)? The code looks like that should already happen, and I don't know where I would even start with changing that. @Dennis

Comment: change `grid[row + 1][col]` to `grid[(row + 1) % len(grid)][col]`, and make similar changes on the other lines